# Struts2 validation problems - not showing right message

Tags: xml, validation, struts2, jsp-tags

I have a big problem with the `struts2` validation.
It's working fine in most of my fields but not in my long fields.

If I enter a string in the long field it's showing an English message instead of my message declared.

> Invalid field value for field "borrower.matNo".

In my `messages_de.properties` it says:

> exception.borrowerMatNo = Bitte geben Sie eine Nummer als
> Matrikelnummer an.

from the validation xml. (Having right name, hundred times checked)

```
<!DOCTYPE validators PUBLIC "-//Apache Struts//XWork Validator 1.0.2//EN" "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/xwork-validator-1.0.2.dtd">
<validators>
   <field name="borrower.matNo">
      <field-validator type="int">
         <param name="min">
         1</param>
         <param name="max">
         100000</param>
         <message key="exception.borrowerMatNo"/>
      </field-validator>
   </field>
</validators>
```

From the jsp:

```
<s:form action="searchBorrower">
   <s:textfield key="borrower.matNo" />
   <s:submit key="search" />
</s:form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Invalid field value is not a problem of the valdation.xml. It's the Struts2 TypeConversion error. To setup I18n messages try the following:

```
invalid.fieldvalue.borrower.matNo=Please enter the correct format.
```